# Discord.js v13 Bot doesn't collect messages in DMChannel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a captcha verification system for my discord bot. So when someone join a server the bot will DM the user a captcha and the user have to solve the captcha in a given time period to get a specific role in the server but my bot doesn't seem to collect the user's message. I've tried different ways to fix this problem. Here are some ways that I've tried :

**1. Using createMessageCollector()**

```
        const filter = (message) => {
            if (message.author.id !== member.id) return;
            if (message.content === captcha.text) return true;
            else member.send("Wrong captcha")
        }
        const msg = await member.send({files : [captchaAttachment], embeds: [captchaEmbed], content: captcha.text })

        const collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ["time"]})

        collector.on('collect', () => {
            member.roles.add("1009431897694294017");
            member.send("You have been verified")
        })

        collector.on('end', async () => {
            await member.send("you have not been verified and have kicked from the server")
            member.kick()
        })
```

**2. Using awaitMessages() with try...catch**

```
        const filter = (message) => {
            if (message.author.id !== member.id) return;
            if (message.content === captcha.text) return true;
            else member.send("Wrong captcha")
        }
        const msg = await member.send({files : [captchaAttachment], embeds: [captchaEmbed], content: captcha.text })
        try {
            const response = await msg.channel.awaitMessages({filter: filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ["time"]})
            if (response) {
                member.roles.add("1009431897694294017")
                member.send("You have been verified")
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            await member.send("you have not been verified and have kicked from the server")
            member.kick()
        }
```

**3. Using awaitMessages() with Promise**

```
        const filter = (message) => {
            if (message.author.id !== member.id) return;
            if (message.content === captcha.text) return true;
            else member.send("Wrong captcha")
        }
        await member.send({files : [captchaAttachment], embeds: [captchaEmbed], content: captcha.text })
            .then((msg) => {
                msg.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ["time"] })
                    .then(() => {
                        member.roles.add("1009431897694294017");
                        member.send("You have been verified")
                    })
                    .catch(async () => {
                        await member.send("you have not been verified and have kicked from the server")
                        member.kick()
                    })
            })
```

All of the snippets above have the same result as shown in this picture : [Captcha Bot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQKA1.png)

As you can see the user have already solved the captcha but the bot didn't collect the message so it threw an error.

I've also tried removing the filter because I thought that's the source of the problem but that didn't seem to resolve it.

I also noticed that I only got this problem in [DMChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/DMChannel). I've tried collecting messages in [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/TextChannel) via [Interaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/Interaction) and the [Message Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You always have a `catch` block but you never check what the error is?

Comment: The code reached the `catch` block because the Collector didn't collect any message given by the recipient in a given time period (10 seconds) so it threw an error (`errors: ["time"]`). I tried to print the error and it printed this :
`Collection(0) [Map] {}`
As you can see, somehow, no message was collected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. Turned out it had something to do with the Discord [Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) that I was using. Here is the intents that I was using :

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
```

Then I realized that I actually need to add the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` Intent. So the right `Client` instance should be like this :

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES] });
```